日本の株価の1分足のデータをリアルタイムで取得したい
プログラミングというより情報交換のような話になってしまうのですが・・・。
現在Node.js(JavaScript)でアメリカのYahoo!Financeから1分足を取得しています。
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/chart/7203.T?range=1d&interval=1m&indicators=quote&includeTimestamps=true
このデータを取得すると、トヨタ自動車の株価について1分足が今日一日分取得できます。
JSONの形で取得されたのを整形すると次のようになります（最新の一部のみ掲載）。
code    exchange    brand   date    weekday open    high    low close   volume
7203    T   トヨタ自動車(株)   240513_1500 Mon 3366    3366    3366    3366    0
7203    T   トヨタ自動車(株)   240513_1459 Mon 3366    3368    3363    3363    229000
7203    T   トヨタ自動車(株)   240513_1458 Mon 3367    3368    3366    3366    67400
7203    T   トヨタ自動車(株)   240513_1457 Mon 3364    3368    3364    3367    90800
7203    T   トヨタ自動車(株)   240513_1456 Mon 3363    3365    3363    3364    75100
7203    T   トヨタ自動車(株)   240513_1455 Mon 3364    3364    3361    3363    132700
7203    T   トヨタ自動車(株)   240513_1454 Mon 3365    3365    3362    3364    215400
7203    T   トヨタ自動車(株)   240513_1453 Mon 3366    3367    3365    3365    29900
7203    T   トヨタ自動車(株)   240513_1452 Mon 3368    3368    3366    3366    88000
7203    T   トヨタ自動車(株)   240513_1451 Mon 3370    3371    3367    3367    116300
7203    T   トヨタ自動車(株)   240513_1450 Mon 3370    3371    3368    3369    131100
データ取得に問題はないのですが、本日ザラ場中に試してみて、データが20分遅れということに気づきました。リアルタイムで取得する方法についてご存知の方がいらっしゃれば情報を共有いただけると幸いです。
楽天証券のマーケットスピードIIはExcelの関数になってしまうので、できればAPIでJavaScriptやPythonなどプログラムで取得できるとうれしいです。
有料サービスでも多少の費用なら出す覚悟です。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

おそらく大元の情報がどのように提供されているかがこちらリアルタイム情報 - 概要、そして二次的に提供している業者のリストがこちらリアルタイム情報 - 情報提供会社等、どの業者がどのような方式・遅延・料金などで個人にも提供しているかについては、誰かがどこかでまとめているかもしれませんが、その辺はご自身で探してみてください。出てきた中には少し古いですがこんな記事もあります。AWSを通じて日本取引所グループ(JPX)のarrownetにアクセスをする、【保存版】TradingViewのリアルタイム表示と遅延理由・解消方法｜株・先物チャートはなぜ遅れる！？

kunif さんありがとうございます！概要がよくわかりました。リアルタイムデータと20分遅延データを東証がまず提供しているんですね。無知すぎて知りませんでした。どの業者がリアルタイムデータを提供しているのか一応探してみたつもりですが、もう一度調べ直してみますね。情報役に立ちました。ありがとうございました。
